# local host not responding when ejs templates are added

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

local host is not loading when partials(ejs templates)  are added to the pages.The page loads at first if the partials are not added.But once the partials are added the page no longer loads.Also no error is also being reported.The page keeps on loading and finally shows unable to reach the adress.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyparser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");


app.get("/", function(req , res){
    res.render("landing");
});

app.get("/campgrounds", function(req,res){
   res.render("campgrounds",{campgrounds:campgrounds});
});

app.post("/campgrounds",function(req,res){
    var name = req.body.name;
    var image = req.body.image;
    var newCamp = {name: name, image:image}
    campgrounds.push(newCamp)
    res.redirect("/campgrounds");
});

app.get("/campgrounds/new", function(req, res){
    res.render("new.ejs");
});
app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Yelp camp server has started");
});
```

when the headers are added to the the following page the page no longer loads

```
 <%- include('partials/header.ejs') %>

<h1>landing page</h1>

<a href="/campgrounds">view all campgrounds</a>
<p>asdasdasda</p>

<%- include('partials/footer.ejs') %>
```

Please help!!!!
also here is the code for the header

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>YELPCAMP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    </head>

<body>
<p>header tabs</p>
```

Comment: Didn't work. This only happens when adding the header.if the footer is added in place of the header it works . But when the header is added it is not working
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `-` from the closing tag:

```
<%- include('partials/header.ejs') -%>

...

<%- include('partials/footer.ejs') -%>
```

Comment: Didn't work. This only happens when adding the header.if the footer is added in place of the header it works . But when the header is added it is not working

Comment: @JoelJose try removing the `ejs` extension. See if it works like this: `<%- include('partials/header') -%>`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help ,
The problem was occurring because of an incorrect bootstrap cdn and the partials declaration.
Fixed those issues and the app is now working fine.